# Turtle and Kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy, turtle-graphics

I have been playing with basic Python and be familiar with Turtle module in Python. Then, I download Kivy, and write some basic application with that.

my problem is that I couldn't use Turtle module in Kivy. I search a lot, but I couldn't find any example or tutorial on it.

is it possible to use turtle module in Kivy application?

is there any example to use turtle in their Kivy application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default turtle gui uses tkinter (a different graphics toolkit), it can't draw in a kivy app. You can certainly use the turtle module with Kivy, it should be very easy to draw the turtle's path, but you'd need to write some code to actually do this - turning the turtle position stuff into kivy graphics instructions.